# Deprecated API Android and iPhone

Tags: android, ios, deprecated

I am making application which is using a deprecated API. I have to submit it on Apple and Android App Store next month.

In this case, is there any chances to reject the application from app Store of iPhone and Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a deprecated API. Almost nobody deprecates something without providing an alternate means to accomplish the same task. Use the documentation to discover these alternatives, and adjust your code accordingly. What happens if iOS 5 comes out tomorrow, for instance, and all of a sudden your code breaks on those devices. You'll be scrambling to fix it. Fix it now while you have some time.

Comment: will it run on the old devices which contain the older versions of iphone and android...

Comment: This is what conditionals are for. If the new method isn't available on older firmware versions which you wish to target, check for the new api, if it's available, use it. Otherwise, use the old API.

Answer (score 0):

Android should not be a problem due to the fact that they won't look at your code. Apple will probably check your code and if they see it, they will most likely tell you that you are using deprecated API, but I don't think they will reject it if it is working flawlessly with it.

Comment: Apple will not tell you you're using a deprecated API.

Comment: deprecated api cause any problem to newer versions of iphone and android?